# How to access memory file in wxWidgets?

Tags: html, c++, wxwidgets

I have a code that writes a JPG file to memory:

```
wxMemoryFSHandler::AddFile("radius.jpg", bmp.ConvertToImage(), wxBITMAP_TYPE_JPEG);
```

I used it to view it in an HTML viewer and it works great. But now I want to access this file in memory myself. How do I get an object like `wxFile` for a file stored in memory?

The thing is, I want to save a file from `wxHtmlWindow` as a *single* html file, using `<img src="data:`.

So I need an in-memory image of a JPG file to convert it to base64 and add it to an html file. How can I do it?

Perhaps I'm doing it too hard, and is there an easier solution to save a single html file? I would be grateful if someone could point me to this method. The html file and images are generated by the program as a result of some scientific calculations and are not saved on disk.

Comment: The `bmp` is written to a file.  Rather than going from `bmp` to the file, then reading the file, you could access the `bmp` object directly and I bet it resides in memory.

Comment: I am confused.  The function `AddFile` saves to a file, which most of the time on os a disk. So how are they not saved to disk?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Pay attention to `Memory` in `wxMemoryFSHandler`. I don't have any file on disk, it is generated and **ALREADY** stored in memory as a JPG. Why should I save it to disk and immediately re-read it into memory? Making a second copy in memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wxFileSystem](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_file_system.html) to access virtual file system contents.
This is unfortunately not well-explained in the docs, but you use its `OpenFile()` member function with `memory:radius.jpg` parameter to get a `wxFSFile` representing the file contents -- and from there you can use its `GetStream()` to get its data.

Comment: I carefully reviewed the example. There is creating your own file system, but not an example of how to work with an existing `memory:` file system. How do I access a file located in memory, this example does not show :( Or I didn't understand. Then please explain in more detail.

Comment: Sorry for the misdirection, I thought this sample showed how to do it, but it indeed doesn't :-( I've update the answer to try to explain this.